# Weil's Riemann Hypothesis for curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am looking at *The Riemann Hypothesis over Finite Fields:
From Weil to the Present Day*, by James S. Milne, present in the book *The Legacy of
Bernhard Riemann
After One Hundred
And Fifty Years* (https://www.jmilne.org/math/xnotes/pRH.html)
and I cannot find out a passage.
Take $V$ to be the product of two curves, $V=C_1\times C_2$. Identify $C_1$ and $C_2$ with the
curves $C_1\times pt$ and $pt\times C_2$
on $V$. Let $D$ be a divisor on $C_1\times C_2$ and set $d_1=D.C_1$ and $d_2= D.C_2$. Now, let $f:C_1\rightarrow C_2$ be a nonconstant morphism and $g_i$ be the genus of $C_i$.
The graph of $f$ is a divisor $\Gamma_f$ on $C_1\times C_2$ with $d_2=1$ and $d_1=\deg f$, and define the equivalence defect to be $\text{def }f=2d_1d_2-D^2$.
In the exercise 1.7 page 10 it is proven the equivalence $\text{def }(\Gamma_f)=2g_2\text{deg }f $, then in the next paragraph they use this result to prove Weil's analogue for the Riemann Hypothesis for curves. If $\Delta,\,\pi$  are respectively the diagonal morphism and the Froboenius endomorphism, they implicitly say that $\text{deg }(\Delta)=1$ and $\text{deg }(\pi)=q$. Why are these two last equalities true?

Comment: The Frobenius endomorphim of a curve over $\Bbb{F}_q\subset k$ always has degree $q$, this is because $k(C)$ is a separable extension of $k(t)$ so $k(C) =k(C)^q(t)$ and $[k(C):k(C)^q]=q$.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. And for the diagonal?